# Verify with delay and rejects take a lot of time to run tests

Tags: ocmock

My project use OCMock, OHHTTPStubs and XCTest.
I try to test SDK (SDK implemented by my), so i stub Http response/requests and add some expectation on callback methods. Each unit tests have some expectations that delegate methods will be called properly and after setting all expectations i included rejects for each delegate method to be sure that only specified methods will be called and nothing more.

Example of my unit test:

```
// stub http
... here are some http stubs...

// expect 

[[self.mockDelegate expect] didSomethigHappend:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj) {

    BOOL result = NO;
    // testing parameter object

    if(result) {
        // call next method on SDK
        [self.objectToTest nextMethod];
    }
    return result;

}] withError:[OCMArg isNil]];

// reject any other call:
[[self.mockDelegate reject] didSomethigHappend:[OCMArg any] withError:[OCMArg any]];
[[self.mockDelegate reject] dodSomethig2:[OCMArg any] withError:[OCMArg any]];
[[self.mockDelegate reject] dodSomethig3:[OCMArg any] withError:[OCMArg any]];

[super.objectToTest doSomethigWithDelegate:super.mockDelegate]; // run

[super.mockDelegate verifyWithDelay:3];  // verify
```

All tests pass successfully but it take a lot of time to run everything. But what i saw, when i remove those rejects all tests run 3 times faster.
After some debuging i check the implementation of OCMock library method:

```
- (void)verifyWithDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay atLocation:(OCMLocation *)location
{
    NSTimeInterval step = 0.01;
    while(delay > 0)
    {
        if([expectations count] == 0)
            break;
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:step]];
        delay -= step;
        step *= 2;
    }
    [self verifyAtLocation:location];
}
```

And where rejects are registered the "expectations" variable always contains those rejects so it waits all delay time.

Anybody have the same problem ?
Maybe i do something wrong and this is correct behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that OCMock have a bug.

Here is workaround with method swizzling:

```
// stubbing verify with delay from ocmock framework
// because ocmock if has any registered rejects
// waits whole specified time, so we need to change this flow
// so it will wait for all expectation has occure and after that wait some steps to make sure that any reject has not invoked

static dispatch_once_t swizzle_token;
dispatch_once(&swizzle_token, ^{
    SEL originalSelector = @selector(verifyWithDelay:);
    SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(fake_verifyWithDelay:);

    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([OCMockObject class], originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([VDFUsersServiceBaseTestCase class], swizzledSelector);

    BOOL didAddMethod =
    class_addMethod([OCMockObject class],
                    originalSelector,
                    method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                    method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

    if (didAddMethod) {
        class_replaceMethod([OCMockObject class],
                            swizzledSelector,
                            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
});
```

And here is fake_verify method:

```
- (void)fake_verifyWithDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {

NSTimeInterval step = 0.1;
while (delay > 0) {
    @try {
        [self verify];
        break;
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {}
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:step]];
    delay -= step;
    step += 0.1;
}
[self verify];
```

}